# Luna will not start after update

Tags: updates, luna

My OS **Luna** was updated. After starting it again it doesn't work.

It starts and I can see the Elementary logo for a short time. After that I see a black screen with:

```
elementary OS Luna k tty1 
k login:
```

After a short time it shows automatically:

```
elementary OS Luna k tty1 
k login: [ 367.090627] iwl4965 0000:03:00.0 Aggregation not enabled for tid 0 because load = 5
```

after a few minutes it shows

```
[109.150665] Aggregation not enabled for tid 0 because load = 1
```

If I type in my login quickly when the black screen is shown I can't enter, because it asks for a password, but it is not shown that I type in anything and it sys that the login is incorrect.

What is the difference between the login and the password?

Wait. I guess I entered. but the black screen is still there. But I can run "ls" and I can see my folders at least.

What do I have to do to use elementary OS like before?

Why doesn't it start like before?

What can I do?

I can't use my laptop anymore and I don't have access to any data on it. Please help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try this: boot to advanced options for elementary OS then select latest kernel.

Comment: thanks a lot! I used GRUB to boot from another Kernel. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution :

Select advanced options for elementary OS , while booting.

Select latest `kernel`